# Tried to commit to GithHub directly from Xcode 14 and keep getting error message, but when I check GitHub everything commits perfectly fine?

Tags: github, xcode14

So I've been trying to get my code onto GitHub after accidentally deleting one of my projects. I went into Xcode settings and connected my GitHub account under source control accounts. Then I went to source control > commit[[Source Control SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti6R1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myVQC.png) and I just keep getting the error message "Authentication failed because the credentials were rejected. [Credentials SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0VJG.png) But when I go to GitHub and check my repositories, I see all of my changes and everything has committed just fine. So why do I keep getting the error even though it commits like it's supposed to?

I tried updating my GitHub personal access token, but every time Xcode would continue to insist that my credentials were wrong. Previously I would get a popup that says please sign in again and it required me to put in my access token again, but I no longer see that popup and I only get the error message (even though everything commits perfectly fine).

Comment: Commit should not be doing anything on github. Did you mean push?

Comment: What happens if you do this using the git cli?  A common error on the first push with some editors is that they do not handle adding the github host fingerprint to the known_hosts. I don't know if xcode has this problem. Try to commit and push from the console.